# change an img tag's bottom-width while keeping the original top-width

Tags: python, css, image-processing

here is what i'm trying to do, i want this carpet to have wider bottom so it fits in the background:

[image: rug needs to be 3d]

I'm starting to think there's no way to do this with css;
maybe i could have python script with arguments i can run like
python rug.py "input_img.jpg" "new_bottom_width"
but im no expert at python

i had tried this:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\1997\www\rugs\rug.jpg")
width, height = image.size
new_bottom_width = 800
top_width = 500
width_ratio = new_bottom_width / float(width)
new_height = int(height * width_ratio)
resized_image = image.resize((new_bottom_width, new_height))
left = 0
upper = 0
right = top_width
lower = new_height
cropped_image = resized_image.crop((left, upper, right, lower))
cropped_image.save(r"C:\Users\1997\www\rugs\your_resized_image.jpg")
```

Comment: Investigate CSS 3D.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use perspective and transform: rotateX()? The advantage is that it'll also stretch the image so it looks 3D. See [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/) for details.

```css
body{
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: #222;
}
.container {
  width: fit-content;
  perspective: 100px;
}

.image {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  transform: rotateX(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img class=image src='https://placekitten.com/400/130'>
</div>
```